# How to get pandas row number when index is not like auto_increment.

Tags: python, pandas

df =

[image]

```
df.index[df.item == 'alcohol'][0]
```

it gives me `45`

I want `2`

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If possible create default index values by [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
out = df.index[df.item == 'alcohol'][0]
#generla solution if possible not matched values
out = next(iter(df.index[df.item == 'alcohol']), 'not matched')
```

Solution working with any index values:

```
out = next(iter(np.where(df.item == 'alcohol')[0]), 'not matched')
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'item': ['food','alcohol','drinks']}, index=[23,45,89])
print (df)
       item
23     food
45  alcohol
89   drinks

#test your output
print (df.index[df.item == 'alcohol'][0])
45

#python counts from 0, so for second value get 1
out = next(iter(np.where(df.item == 'alcohol')[0]), 'not matched')
print (out)
1

#condition not matched, so returned empty DataFrame
out = next(iter(np.where(df.item == 'a')[0]), 'not matched')
print (out)
not matched
```

Answer (score 7):

use [pandas.Index.get_loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html)

i.e.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['x'])
df.loc[10] = None
df.loc[20] = None
df.loc[30] = 1

print(df.index.get_loc(30))
>> 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Use index after filtering:

```
df[df.item == 'alcohol'].index
Index(['row 2'], dtype='object')
```

If you want the output to be `2` then:

```
indices = df[df.item == 'alcohol'].index
indices.str[-1:]
Index(['2'], dtype='object')
```

If want a list:

```
indices.str[-1:].tolist()
['2']
```

If the row number is beyond 1 digit then use:

```
indices.extract(r'(\d+)',expand=False)
```

Initial setup:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"index":[23,45,89],"item":['food','alcohol','drinks']},
                  index=['row 1','row 2','row 3'])
df

     index  item
row 1   23  food
row 2   45  alcohol
row 3   89  drinks
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.loc[df['item']== 'alcohol'].index
```

it gives you:

```
Index(['row 2'], dtype='object')
```

If you want the "iloc" position:

```
value_to_find = df.loc[df['item']== 'alcohol'].index.tolist()[0]
row_indexes = df.index.tolist()
position = row_indexes.index(value)
print(position)
```

Note: index start in 0 you are finding 1, right? If you want counting rows

```
position = row_indexes.index(value) + 1
```